# Using Range.TextToColumns to convert to multiple columns does not work

Tags: c#-4.0, csv, vsto, excel-addins

My goal is to convert a single csv string to multiple columns in excel using `Range.TextToColumns()`.

I have a csv file whose columns can contain commas inside them, in that case the column value has double qoutes around it. So to avoid that issue I am just spliting at end of lines to get individual rows. 
My plan is to put each csv row in a single cell in each excel row and use Text to columns function to get my column values staright a way without worrying about the commas inside column values.

Current code:

```
string row = lines[i - 1]; //single CSV row
var startCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[i, 1];
var endCell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[i, 1];
var writeRange = worksheet.get_Range(startCell, endCell);

writeRange.Value2 = row;                                   

startCell.TextToColumns(startCell, XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited
, XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, false
, false, false, true, false, false, false
, XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat, false, false, false);
```

What happens after executing this code is that, I get all the row data in a single cell on each row instead of having multiple columns.

I have written the code in parallel to the manual approach we use while doing Text to Columns in excel sheet, the manual approach yielded expected results but the same thing when done over here in c# is failing.

Please point out mistakes if any in my approach, or show some way out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution. Turns out the msdn guys have messed up the docs on this page:
 [Range.TextToColumns Documentation @msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.texttocolumns%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
startCell.TextToColumns(startCell, Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, missing,
missing, missing, true, missing, missing, missing, missing,
missing, missing, missing);
```

So, instead of writting false, I was supposed to write missing for it to work properly.

[This page helped me figure this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04b02wh9%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)